# Generar una nueva cadena de caracteres, sin los dígitos que coinciden entre cada cadena pasada como argumento, en C

Tags: c

Estoy intentando hacer un programa el cual me genere una nueva cadena de caracteres sin los dígitos que coinciden entre cada cadena; lo que me devuelve la función es "ismo" aunque debería ser "isimo". No entiendo que ocurre cuando termina de recorrer *s2*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[]);

int main(){
    char s1[] = "Buenisimo";
    char s2[] = "Bueno";

    printf("El valor de la s1 es %s\n", s1);
    printf("El valor de la s2 es %s\n", s2);

    squeeze(s1,s2);
    getchar();

}

void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[]){
    int i,j;


    for (i = j = 0 ; s1[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (s1[i] != s2[i])
            s1[j++] = s1[i];

    s1[j] = '\0';
    printf("El nuevo valor de s1 es %s\n",s1);

}
```

Comment: ¿Qué resultado esperas para "Caxdena1" y "Cadena2h"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for (i = j = 0 ; s1[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (s1[i] != s2[i])
            s1[j++] = s1[i];
```

Tienes una cadena de 9 caracteres ('Buenisimo', contando el \0) y otra de 5 caracteres ('Bueno').

Sin embargo, tu código está leyendo de la segunda cadena en las posiciones 5, 6, 7 y 8, **que no son parte de la memoria asignada a esa cadena**. Eso es *undefined behavior* y puede resultar en cualquier cosa.

Tienes que comprobar también si s2[i] == `\0`. Y decidir en tu lógica qué quieres que pase cuando las cadenas no tengan la misma longitud.